# Custom block with a field value that can be used in other twig template

Tags: entities, blocks

I am creating a **custom block** with fields:

- field_items_to_show (items to show)
- field_logos (images, multiple)

**The site editor must have the option to set the amount of items to show in a field.**

in the twig field template `field_logos` I need the value from `field_items_to_show`

```
<div class="logos-slide-out">
    <div class="more-less wrapper d-flex-new flex-column align-items-center">
        <div class="itemstoshow row d-flex-new">
            {% for item in items %}
            {% if loop.index == 9 %} // this value must be set from field_items_to_show
        </div>
        <div class="more-content itemstohide row d-flex-new">
            {% endif %}
            <div class="item col-sm-3 mb-30">{{ item.content }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a field template you find the parent entity in the variable `element['#object']`, from where you can get field values of other fields:

```
{% set field_foo_value = element['#object'].field_foo.value %}
```